# Showing vanishing 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class implies existence of spin structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, principal-bundles, spin-geometry, classifying-spaces

Let $V \rightarrow X$ be an oriented rank-$n$ real vector bundle with equipped with bundle metric. Therefore it gives a classifying map $X\xrightarrow{u} BSO(n)$.

I would like to show that if the 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class of $V$ vanishes then it admits a spin structure. Here is what I have so far:

---

The "universal" 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class, for oriented vector bundles (with metric),
can be identified as the element in $w_2 \in H^2(BSO(n),\mathbb{Z}_2)$ corresponding to the connecting homomorphism $BSO(n)\xrightarrow{h} B^2\mathbb{Z}$
in the classifying-space fiber l.e.s. obtained from a s.e.s. $\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow \mathrm{Spin}(n) \xrightarrow{\phi} SO(n)$.

Thus, $V$ having vanishing 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class implies that the composition $X\xrightarrow{u}BSO(n)\xrightarrow{h} B^2\mathbb{Z}$ is null-homotopic.

It should follow that $u$ factors through a map $X\xrightarrow{v} K$ where $K\rightarrow BSO(n)$ is the "homotopy kernel" of $B^2\mathbb{Z}$.

Note part of the fiber l.e.s. from two paragraphs above is
$B\mathrm{Spin}(n) \xrightarrow{B\phi} BSO(n) \xrightarrow{h} B^2\mathbb{Z}$; therefore we should get a map $B\mathrm{Spin}(n)\rightarrow K$.

My question is, at this point, how do we say we can lift $X\xrightarrow{v} K$ to a map $X\rightarrow B\mathrm{Spin}(n)$?

Comment: It's not a question of lifting, $BSpin(n)$ just is the homotopy fiber of $w_2 : BSO(n) \to B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2$. This follows once you know that $Spin(n)$ is the homotopy fiber of the map $SO(n) \to B \mathbb{Z}_2$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_1$, which is just saying it's the universal cover (when $n \ge 3$ at least).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, thank you. May I ask, is every arrow of the sequence $\cdots B^{k-1}SO\rightarrow B^k\mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow B^k Spin\rightarrow B^k SO \rightarrow \cdots$ a homotopy fiber of the arrow following it? Or, is this specific to the arrows $BSpin(n)\rightarrow BSO(n)\rightarrow B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there for $k \ge 2$. I guess if $w_2$ can be promoted to a map of infinite loop spaces $BSO \to B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2$ then it admits an infinite delooping, in which case that long fiber sequence is by definition given by delooping a suitable number of times and then repeatedly taking homotopy fibers. Maybe it would be helpful to read about long fiber sequences: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+sequence#long_fibration_sequences